# How do I solve the following sum: $x\binom{n}{1}-2x^2\binom{n}{2}+4x^3\binom{n}{3}-...+(-2)^{n-1}x^n\binom{n}{n}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

As the title says, I need to find out if there is any formula for the sum: $S=x\binom{n}{1}-2x^2\binom{n}{2}+4x^3\binom{n}{3}-...+(-2)^{n-1}x^n\binom{n}{n}$ cause I met it in an exercise.

Comment: This is a straightforward application of the binomial theorem.

Comment: @user296602 Isn't the binomial theorem usually $\binom{n}{k}$? This is $\binom{k}{n}$ (where $k$ is the variable being summed over).

Comment: @orlp yes sorry i edited it.

Comment: In that case it is indeed a straight forward application of the binomial theorem.

Comment: @user296602 what do you mean by that? Can you give me a clue?

Comment: @orlp so I can't do anything about it?

Comment: Hint: In the expansion of $(x + y)^n$ try to identify what $x$ and $y$ are.

Comment: Is it $$\binom2n$$ or $$\binom n2$$?

Comment: @OvyOvy Have you tried googling 'binomial theorem'?

Comment: @orlp I know what that is I just did not see that you can write it like $(x+y)^n$ :D. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: $$-2S=\sum_{r=1}^n\binom nr(-2x)^r=?$$

Comment: @SeanRoberson is it $\frac{(1-2x)^n}{-2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let's recall the binomial theorem.

$$ (x + y)^n = \sum_{j = 0}^n \binom{n}{j} x^j y^{n-j} $$

Many sums can be reduced to this by making some identifications. Let's write your sum as

$$ S = \sum_{j = 0}^n \binom{n}{j} \frac{(-1)^j (2x)^j}{2} $$

We don't see a term that looks like $y^{n-j}$ so this is a clue that we may set $y = 1$. We can pull the $\frac{1}{2}$ out to give

$$ S = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j = 0}^n \binom{n}{j} (-1)^j (2x)^j $$

One more thing, let's combine those two things that have $j$ in the exponent.

$$ S = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{j = 0}^n \binom{n}{j} (-2x)^j $$

Now what do we have? We associate to $x$ in the binomial theorem the quantity $-2x$. So, we have that

$$\boxed{S = \frac{(1 - 2x)^n}{2}}$$ done!